# Facet_grid strip label with varying font sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Is it possible to have multiple font sizes in a facet strip? I would like to have a larger font size for the variable in the `facet_grid`, then a smaller font size for some other text (e.g. sample size). I haven't found a way to do this using `strip.text`. Is a labeller function needed?

Here is some example data:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60),20,3)) 
data$veg <- c(rep("Tree (n=2)", 4),rep("Bush (n=4)", 4),rep("Shrubbery (n=6)", 4), rep("Aquatic (n=2)",4),rep("Control (n=7)", 4))
names(data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "veg")
melted <- melt(data)

ggplot(melted, aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(~veg)+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14))
```

In the example below I would like "Aquatic" to be size 14 font and "(n=2)" size 10.

These same font sizes would be applied to all the factors of veg.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no easy solution, however accepted answer in the linked post does exactly what you want.

Comment: what about subscripts i.e. `"Tree[(n==2)]"`, and use `labeller = label_parsed`

Comment: @PoGibas Ok I guess that is as good as I am going to get.